# custom PHP extension

Tags: php, c, compiler-errors, extension-methods

I need to create custom extension for PHP. All things are going well till I want to load compiled extension into PHP. Than I'm getting this error message (by using php -m): **"Warning: PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'first.so' in Unknown on line 0"**

OS:

```
OS X 10.8.5
```

Here is my compiling process thru which there is no error at all :

```
$ phpize54
$ sudo ./configure --with-php-config=/opt/local/bin/php-config54
$ sudo make install
```

I'm registering the extension by .ini file in dir for additional .ini files

```
extension=first.so
```

I'm using no another additional tools. Whan I was trying  to comtile some extension right from the extensions included in sources of PHP distribution (posix, to be concrete) in this way, everything works and extension was loaded correctly.

Does anybody see any mistake in my source code below? Thank U for hellp.

**config.m4**:

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(first,whether to enable FIRST functions,
[  --disable-first         Disable FIRST functions], yes)

if test "$PHP_FIRST" = "yes"; then
  AC_DEFINE(HAVE_FIRST, 1, [whether to include FIRST functions])
  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(first, first.c, $ext_shared)
fi
```

**first.c**

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include "php.h"
#include "ext/standard/info.h"

extern zend_module_entry first_module_entry;
#define first_module_ptr &first_module_entry
#define phpext_first_ptr first_module_ptr


static PHP_MINFO_FUNCTION(first)
{
    php_info_print_table_start();
    php_info_print_table_row(2, "Revision", "$Id: 01 $");
    php_info_print_table_end();
}

static PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(first)
{
    return SUCCESS;
}

PHP_FUNCTION(hallo)
{
    RETURN_STRING("FIRST extension function works\n", 1);
}

ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX(arginfo_hallo, 0, 0, 0)
ZEND_END_ARG_INFO()

const zend_function_entry first_functions[] =
{
    PHP_FE(hallo, arginfo_hallo)
    PHP_FE_END
};

zend_module_entry first_module_entry = {
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
    "first", 
    first_functions, 
    PHP_MINIT(first),
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL, 
    PHP_MINFO(first),
    NO_VERSION_YET,
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

#ifdef COMPILE_DL_POSIX
ZEND_GET_MODULE(first)
#endif
```

Comment: How did you generate the shared library?

Comment: More details are needed to replicate this issue: how are you compiling the code? How are you registering the extension? What tools are you using (ie ext_skel or others), and what errors are you getting (apart from the one you've included in your question)?

Comment: OS: OS X 10.8.5 Here is my compiling process thru which there is no error at all : $ phpize54 $ sudo ./configure --with-php-config=/opt/local/bin/php-config54 $ sudo make install I'm registering the extension by .ini file in dir for additional .ini files extension=first.so I'm using no another additional tools. Whan I was trying to comtile some extension right from the extensions included in sources of PHP distribution (posix, to be concrete) in this way, everything works and extension was loaded correctly.

Comment: you shouldn't use sudo for configure or compilation, you need root privileges only to install the file in the root filesystem (using `make install`). For testing you don't need to `make install either, but can use a relative path (i.e. `php -dextension=modules/foo.so` after make). Using sudo might have bad consequences if there is a bug in the build system or something and also is annoying as suddenly files in your working dir are owned by root needing more sudo, giving more chance of an accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#ifdef COMPILE_DL_POSIX
ZEND_GET_MODULE(first)
#endif
```

This looks wrong. In config.m4 you claim your extension is called first (`PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(first, ...`) but there you are checking whether an extension called posix is built shared.

Background: PHP can load extensions (meaning PHP modules *not* to be confused with Zend Extensions like xdebug or opcache - they are a different topi) in two ways. Either statically compiled into PHP or shared.

Statically means that your extension is built as part of PHP and built right in the php binary. (put it in php-src/ext/, run buildconf, configure) This works by configure creating  a file `main/internal_functions.c` which includes all `php_foo.h` files and creating an array of `module_entry` which is processed at  PHP start.

If an extension is build shared (using `--with-foo=shared` in php-src or `phpize`) and loading it via php.ini PHP will look for a function `get_module()` using `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` system apis (or `LoadDll` on Windows) which will return the module structure. In order to not habe to write that function `get_module()` all the time the macro `ZEND_GET_MODULE` does that. But `get_module` is a common name, and during a static build it has to be prevented that each extension creates it as that would cause a conflict to have the same function multiple times in the same binary, that's why the build system creates COMPILED_DL_FOO defines which can be used as guards.

So in your case PHP opens the library, looks for a `get_module()` but can't find it, shrugs and reports an error.

References:

- http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/dl.c#100 - PHP's module loading routine
- http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_API.h#135 - ZEND_GET_MODULE
- The config.h file in your tree after running configure (search for COMPILE_DL there)